# Find the least absolute value of the sum of product of elements of two arrays, permutation being allowed

Tags: optimization, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Given two arrays $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$ with $\text{M, N}$ elements respectively, minimize :$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{\text{M}} a_i b_{j_i}\right|$$ where $b_j \in B$.

This cannot be boiled down by a direct application of Rearrangement inequality. The absolute value seems to make it difficult.

I'd appreciate a hint for this. If it is difficult to express mathematically (in terms of a closed form or whatever), an algorithm to work this out would also suffice.

Comment: $\left|\sum_{i=1}^{\text{M}} a_i b_j\right|=\left||b_j|\sum_{i=1}^{\text{M}} a_i \right|$ then $n |b_j|\min(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\leq \left|\sum_{i=1}^{\text{M}} a_i b_j\right| \leq n |b_j| \max(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$

Comment: Is $b_j$ fixed, or do you want $j$ to depend on $i$, like $b_{j(i)}$?

Comment: Right. It's $b_{j_i}$ and not a fixed $b$ from array $B$.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this were NP-hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether $a_i$ is matched to $b_j$.  Then the problem is to minimize $z$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
z &\ge \sum_{i,j} a_i b_j x_{i,j}\\
z &\ge -\sum_{i,j} a_i b_j x_{i,j}\\
\sum_j x_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}
If each $b_j$ must appear at most once, then you also need to impose
$$\sum_i x_{i,j} \le 1 \quad \text{for all $j$}.$$